# How to fetch files from S3 to azure blob using logic app

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

On my S3 bucket, I have a folder structure similar to this -  Year -> Month -> Day -> Hour I receive files in .gz format every minute on S3. How can I push these files to ADLS gen2 through logic apps? Also, when the file is pulled from the S3 bucket, it must be unzipped

[image]

Comment: You just gotta do the work man.  I'd suggest a lambda on the AWS side that sends the contents of the file to a HTTP endpoint in LogicApps and from there, it can do the work to dump it to a storage container.  Where you unzip it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample that worked for me to achieve your requirement. You can apply something similar in your case. Currently, I have 2 .gz files in my S3 account.

[image]

I have used Azure data factory in order to extract the files in my S3 account and to send it to the ADLS gen2. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

For the pipeline in my Azure data factory, I have used Copy data where the source dataset would be from S3 Account and Sink dataset would be the ADLS Gen 2, both are of binary type.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After successful run I can see that my files are being extracted to my ADLS gen2.

[image]

Note: Here I'm just trying to get the file names (key) from logic apps and sending it to data factory in order to get the file from S3 to ADLS for extraction.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, Swetha. I already have an ADF pipeline that fulfils this requirement. Due to the fact that I run this pipeline almost every two minutes, the costs are pretty high using copy activity. For this reason, I looked for help to complete this task using logic apps to minimize costs.